# Float right in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-float

I want to create vertical navbar on right side in React using flexbox and in the middle would be a login element that I don't have access to. Problem is that using justify-content: flex-end. Element is moved to right side but Login element is below instead of in the center.

I tried using position: absolute, inherit. But Login elements would overlap. I also tried using z-index, but it's similar. z-index -1; Good for login bad for navbar. z-index 10: good for navbar bad for login.

Usually I would just use float: right on navbar and be done with it. But I would like to know if there is a solution with flexbox.

[image: Expected result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think flexbox is the right tool for this layout. It could be, if the login form was centered relative to the space left by the navbar (which could make more sense than centered relative to the whole body). Here it seems the navbar is indeed `float: right` or `position: fixed`. The layout specified here makes overlapping inevitable for smaller screen sizes, so yeah you need to define the behaviour when that happens.